# Notification Big Text Android GCM

Tags: android, android-layout, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I'm having trouble getting Android's Big Text notifications to work as documented here: [NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle.html). Here's the code I'm using to display notifications. I know all the data is coming back correctly because I can get it to display on the console and as the traditional content text and title. Am I doing something wrong? Do I need to define bigTestStyle somewhere else as well? Hopefully one of you has done this before and knows what could be missing. Thanks.

[image: As you can see the big text message text is not displaying]

My code:

```
    NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle bigTextStyle = new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle();
    bigTextStyle.bigText(extras.getString("message"));
    NotificationCompat.Builder bigTextNotification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setContentTitle("My App")
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setContentText("Message:")
            .setSound(soundUri)
            .setTicker(extras.getString("message"))
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.splash)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setVibrate(new long[] { 0, 100, 200, 300 })
            .setStyle(bigTextStyle);
    final int notificationId = (int) (System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L);
    NotificationManager thisone = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    thisone.notify(notificationId, bigTextNotification.build());
```

Comment: I have a micromax canvas A74,Android version 4.2.2.Using `NotificationCompat` worked fine for me.However when i use `Notification.Bulider`, `BigTextStyle` works fine but the normal notification style doesn't work.It justs display the notification icon without any text in it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle.html) documentation :

> Helper class for generating large-format notifications that include a lot of text.
>   **If the platform does not provide large-format notifications, this method has no effect**. The user will always see the normal notification view.

Perhaps your platform doesn't support large-format notifications.

**EDIT :**

On the other hand, it's possible your problem is here :

```
NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle bigTextStyle = new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle();
bigTextStyle.bigText(extras.getString("message"));
```

You are not using the return value of `bigText`.

Try to change it to :

```
NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle bigTextStyle = new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle();
bigTextStyle  = bigTextStyle.bigText(extras.getString("message"));
```

or to :

```
NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle bigTextStyle = new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(extras.getString("message"));
```

**EDIT2 :**

Costom Notification Layout for older Android versions :

```
protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // Extract the payload from the message
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        String message = (String) extras.get("message");
        String title = (String) extras.get("title");                

        // add a notification to status bar
        NotificationManager mManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(this,MyActivity.class);
        Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.notification_image, title, System.currentTimeMillis());
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

        RemoteViews contentView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.custom_notification);
        contentView.setImageViewResource(R.id.image, R.drawable.notification_image);
        contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.title, title);
        contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.text, message);
        notification.contentView = contentView;
        notification.contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this.getBaseContext(), 0, myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        mManager.notify(0, notification);
        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) 
        context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, "TAG");
        wl.acquire(15000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Neither of those worked. Not sure if bigTextStyle is being built as part of bigTextNotification

Comment: In that case it's possible your device or Android version don't support large-format notifications.

Comment: Since you have a new device, I'm assuming you have a new Android version installed. I suggest you try using `Notification.BigTextStyle` instead of `NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle`, and see if it works.

Comment: Ok that got it working. Is there any way to achieve a similar effect (lots of text in notification center) in APIs before 16?

Comment: Do you have the latest version of the compatibility library? Perhaps a newer version would work better.

Comment: What do you mean you don't? the `NotificationCompat` class is part of the compatibility library (also called [Support Library](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html)) which allows you to use new features in older API levels.

Comment: I got the v13 one now and it still won't display properly on older devices.

Comment: I thought you were testing it on your S3. Older devices might not support large-format notifications.

Comment: Yeah now that I have it working on a new device thanks to your code, I'd like to go older. Is that possible with this or another method?

Comment: Does it work on your new device when using the `NotificationCompat` class, or only when you use the API16 class? If it works with `NotificationCompat` on the new device, then the devices for which it doesn't work simply don't support it. If `NotificationCompat` doesn't work in the new device, either there's a bug in that class, or there's something wrong with your usage of that class.

Comment: I've read about custom layouts for older versions of android. Do you know anything about that?

Comment: I do, but the total space of the notification remains fixed as far as I know. In order to fit longer text you'll have to reduce the font size.

Comment: Can you post a link or two to get me started? I only need a couple more letters. My client is only sending 15-20 word notifications out

Comment: I added a code sample for custom notification layout to my answer.