# Android- Multiple line notification is not working

Tags: java, android

firstly, I read [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle.html) and use this simple code to multiple notification:

```
    public static void notifyMessage()
    {
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
     int notifyID = 1;
     NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
            context);
    int numMessages = 0;
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
            .setContentTitle("Event tracker")
            .setContentText("Events received")
            .setNumber(++numMessages)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis()).setAutoCancel(true)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
            .bigText("bigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbig"));
    Notification notification = builder.build();
    notificationManager.notify(1, notification);
```

It's working. if message's length is bigger than usual limit , it will show "*bigbig...*".
 in next step, I want use user's message to show in notification. so I've changed function to :

```
      public static void notifyMessage(String message , boolean flashLed)
    {
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
     int notifyID = 1;
     NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
            context);
    int numMessages = 0;
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
            .setContentTitle("Event tracker")
            .setContentText(message)
            .setNumber(++numMessages)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis()).setAutoCancel(true)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
            .bigText(message));
    if (flashLed)
    {
        builder.setLights(0xFFFF0000, 500, 500);
    }
    Notification notification = builder.build();
    notificationManager.notify(1, notification);
}
```

I trying to show **message** instead of "*bigbigbig....*" but always it show me short type of notification. I've also tried this:

```
  public static void notifyMessage(String message)
    {
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

     NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
            context);
     NotificationCompat.InboxStyle inboxStyle =
                    new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle();
     String[] events = new String[4];
            // Sets a title for the Inbox in expanded layout
     events[0] = message.substring(0, 15);
     events[1] = message.substring(15, 35);
     events[2] = message.substring(35, 55);
     events[3] = message.substring(55, 75);
     inboxStyle.setBigContentTitle("Event tracker details:");

      // Moves events into the expanded layout
    for (int i=0; i < events.length; i++) {

       inboxStyle.addLine(events[i]);
    }
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
            .setContentTitle("Event tracker"")
            .setContentText("Events received")
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis()).setAutoCancel(true)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
            .setStyle(inboxStyle);

    Notification notification = builder.build();
    notificationManager.notify(1, notification);
}
```

but application getting crash when new message arrive. How to change second or third function?

Comment: Refer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20748049/android-multiple-line-notification-like-gmail-app

Comment: This may help:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16490048/notification-big-text-android-gcm

Comment: @DineshPrajapati I've already read it , and use BigTextStyle()

Comment: Check expanded layout in that tutorial, it will allow you to add the content as lines, which will solve the problem

Comment: @DineshPrajapati I trying to use it in third function but it's not working

Comment: @AFN ...Have you resolved your proble..I have also stucked in same kind of problem....please help

Answer (score 0):

remove content from `.setContentText("")`

Instead add:

```
.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                                .bigText(message));
```

Example:

```
 NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .setSmallIcon(GetNotificationIcon())
                        .setContentTitle(Constants.APP_NAME)
                        .setContentText("")
                        .setSound(uri)
                        .setVibrate(vibrate)
                        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                                .bigText(message));
```

Comment: Yep. A blank notification

Comment: Depends on OS version.

Answer (score -1):

Please see this link - https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html

```
    NotificationCompat.InboxStyle inboxStyle =
            new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle();
    // Sets a title for the Inbox in expanded layout
      inboxStyle.setBigContentTitle("bigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbigbig");
   // Moves the expanded layout object into the notification object.
      builder.setStyle(inBoxStyle);
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of setting the style directly to the builder add the text message to the style and then add the BigTextStyle to builder.
Try to replace the following line

```
setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
```

with

```
NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle bigText = new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle();
        bigText.bigText("Your long message");
        builder.setStyle(bigText);
```

Comment: What is the version of your andrroid mobile

Answer (score -1):

I have checked that Last method is working fine for me. Make sure you are using updated **Support V4** library.

You can download from  [here](https://goo.gl/uWUZKB).

Copy library in libs folder and do **clean** & **build** project and then **run** application.

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score -1):

The following code works for me.

```
 NotificationManager manager= (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)

                .setContentTitle("title")
                .setContentText("message")
                .setLargeIcon(bitmap)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notif)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg))
                .setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_ALL)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
                .setAutoCancel(true);

        builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        manager.notify(requestID, builder.build())
```