# NotificationCompat.Builder BigTextStyle().bigText(messageBody) not working on 5.1.1 when app background

Tags: android, notifications, google-cloud-messaging

I've implemented FCM notification on my app and it's working, but I want to show all messageBody in the notification using BigTextStyle().bigText.

The problem is that only appears all message when app is in screen. When the app's backgrounded, the notification only shows a few words.

Android's version device: 5.1.1

Hope help, please!

These are the screenshots:

Whith app in screen
[enter link description here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4nh84fw6dn7s1j3/inScreenApp.png?dl=0)
Whith app backgrounded
[enter link description here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/a1jkzadurt7wyuw/backgroundedApp.png?dl=0)

```
private void sendNotification(String messageBody) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);



    Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

    android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("Essencia café y copas")
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(messageBody))
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)                
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

Comment: please share screenshots\

Comment: I've just updated post and shared the screenshots

Answer (score 0):

It might be because your platform doesn't support large-format notifications.

When using `NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle` method, as stated in [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle.html):

> If the platform does not provide large-format notifications, this method has no effect. The user will always see the normal notification view.

You may also try to go over [Anatomy of a Notification](https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/notifications.html#Anatomy) to cover basic parts of a notification and how they can appear on different types of devices. Using **expanded layouts**:

> You can choose how much detail your app's notifications should provide. They can show the first few lines of a message or show a larger image preview. The additional information provides the user with more context, and—in some cases—may allow the user to read a message in its entirety.

Apart from the discussions, suggested solution given in this SO post - [Notification Big Text Android GCM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16490048/notification-big-text-android-gcm) that using `Notification.BigTextStyle` instead of `NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle` might help.